# Django: django-tables2 Changing default sort behaviour

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I'm experimenting with django-tables2. I've created a test site that displays a column of dates (created by `timezone.now()`). By default, the dates are ordered Oldest->Newest. If I click on column header, the dates are displayed in reverse order (the desired default behavior).

I've played around with the `order_by` argument, but I'm doing something wrong. My tables.py:

```
class OrderTable(tables.Table):
    order_date = tables.Column(order_by=("Order Date",))
```

My views.py:

```
def index(request):
    table = OrderTable(Order.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request, paginate={"per_page": 10}).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'orders_app/index.html', {'table': table})
```

How can I order the "Order Date" column so its displayed as Newest->Oldest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just prefix a `'-'` before the column name to reverse the order. You can supply `order_by` at the time of initializing the table.

```
def index(request):
    table = OrderTable(Order.objects.all(), order_by="-order_date")
    RequestConfig(request, paginate={"per_page": 10}).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'orders_app/index.html', {'table': table})
```

---

See [`order_by`](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#Table.Meta.order_by):

> The default ordering. e.g. `('name', '-age')`. A hyphen `-` can be used to prefix a column name to indicate descending order.

Also, see [specifying alternative ordering for a column](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#specifying-alternative-ordering-for-a-column)

Comment: My apologies. I've revised the answer, it should fit your needs.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this with multiple values?

Answer (score 2):

You can either set ordering on your queryset like this:

```
table = OrderTable(Order.objects.order_by('-Order Date'))
```

or using the table object directly:

```
table = OrderTable(Order.objects.all())
table.order_by = '-Order Date'
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. It looks like I have to specify the actual variable name '-order_date' instead of '-Order Date'.

Comment: Well, you should edit your question then, you specified that the column name is "Order Date", clearly you have the "order_date" attribute in your model ...

Comment: I meant "column" as in what is rendered by the browser. Clearly I can't have spaces in variable names.

Comment: Well you can in your database ... anyway, i think you got it working